# $S\Delta T = T$ (where S and T are sets and $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference between them). Is $ S = \phi $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just proved the following results: 
$S \Delta T =  (T \cup S) \cap ( S \cap T)' $ 
$S \Delta T =  (T \cap S') \cup ( S \cap T') $ 
I thought I could equate one of these with T and see if I get any results. But I'm unable to draw any conclusions. 
How do I find the answer?

Comment: Suppose $S\neq \emptyset$ and let $s\in S$.  Now, one of two things will be true, either $s\in T$ as well or $s\not\in T$.  In the first case, will $s$ be an element of $S\triangle T$?  Will $s$ be an element of $T$?  In the second case, will $s$ be an element of $S\triangle T$?  Will $s$ be an element of $T$?  What does that tell you?

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you. I got the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in S$.

Either $x \in T$ or $x$ is not in $T$.  If $x\in T=S\Delta T$ then $x \not \in T$.  A contradiction.

If $x \not \in T$ then $x \in S\Delta T = T$.  A contradiction.

So $x \in S$ leads to a contradiction so $S$ is empty.

====

Alternatively.  $S\Delta T = (S\cap T^c) \cup (T\cap S^c)$.  If $(S\cap T^c) \cup (T\cap S^c) = T$ then $S\cap T^c \subset T$.  But $S\cap T^c \subset T^c$ and $T^c$ and $T$ are disjoint so $S\cat T^c$ are disjoint so $S\cap T^c = \emptyset$.  So $S\Delta T = T\cap S^c = T$.

Not $T\cap S \subset T$ so $T\cap S \subset T\cap S^c$. But $T\cap S\subset S$ and $T\cap S^c \subset S^c$. $S$ and $S^c$ are disjoint so their subsets are disjoint so $T\cap S \subset T\cap S^c$ implies $T\cap S=\emptyset$.

So $S\cap T^c = \emptyset$ and $S\cap T = T\cap S = \emptyset$.  So $S = (S\cap T)\cup (S\cap T^c) =\emptyset \cup \emptyset=\emptyset$.

(This assumes the existance of a universal set so that $A\subset U; B\subset U$.  It's safe to assume there is one.  But if not we can always simply declare $U =A\cup B$ and $A^c= U\setminus A$ and $B^c = U\setminus B$.)

======

Alternatively: Venn Diagrams:

Consider $X = S\setminus T; Y= T\setminus S; Z= S\cap T$.  These sets partition $A\cup B$:  These sets are mutually distinct and $X\cup Y \cup Z = A\cup B$.

So if $x \in A\cup B$ then *exactly* one of the following is true $x\in X; x\in Y; x\in Z$.

$S\Delta T = X \cup Y$,  $S = X\cup  Z$, $T=Y\cup Z$.

If $X\cup Y = S\Delta T = T=Y\cup Z$.

Let $x \in A\cup B$.

Then if $x \in X$ then $x\in X\cup Y =Y\cup Z$.  So $x\in Y$ or $x\in Z$.  But that contradicts the uniqueness of an element being in exactly one of the sets.

If $x \in Y$ then we get not contradiction.  $x \in T$ an $x\not \in S$.

If $x \in Z$ then $x\in Y\cup Z = X\cup Y$.  So $x \in Y$ or $X$ which contradicts uniqueness.

So $x \in Y$ is the only possibility for any element in $A\cup B$.  So $x \in S = X\cup Z$ implying $x \in X$ or $x \in Y$ is impossible.  So $S = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Since equality is equivalent to double inclusion, you deduce that $S \Delta T \subset T$ so $S \setminus T = \emptyset$ which implies $S \subset T$ and $S \Delta T = T \setminus S$.

If $S \neq \emptyset$, then $S \Delta T \neq T $ so $S$ is necessarily empty.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Iverson brackets$$S\triangle T=\{x|[x\in S]+[x\in T]=1\},\,T=\{x|[x\in T]=1\}.$$These sets are equal iff $[x\in S]=0$ for all $x$, i.e. $S=\emptyset$. While this helps to give an arithmetic intuition, if you want a purer set-theoretic argument note $\forall x\in S(x\in S\triangle T\iff x\notin T)$, yet if $S\triangle T=T$ then $\forall x(x\in S\triangle T\iff x\in T)$, which forces a contradiction iff $\exists x(x\in S)$. By contrast, if $S=\emptyset$ then trivially $S\triangle T=T$.